# getting different URLs in my wp_footer() call on different servers

Tags: wordpress

i have two wordpress blogs on two digitalocean servers

both use a variant of the same theme (roots) and have the `wp_footer()` call right before body

however: on one blog, the full URL is returned in the script calls:
`src=https://newsroom.guidevine.com/wp-includes/js/wp-embed.min.js?ver=4.7`

and in the other, i get the relative URL:
`/wp-includes/js/wp-embed.min.js?ver=4.7`

what gives? it's driving me nuts.

Comment: What do you use in script to show full url?

Comment: i think this is some server config issue:

`<?= get_template_directory_uri(); ?>` gives the full URL on both blogs.

this is the `wp-embed` call in `wp-includes/embed.php`

--

`function wp_oembed_add_host_js() {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-embed' );
}`

Comment: both blog have https?

Comment: yep - see line 1154 (use chrome) on this source:
view-source:https://www.guidevine.com/roundtable

////

and line 1191 on this one:
view-source:https://www.guidevine.com/roundtable

////

you will see how one is absolute, and the other relative. (diasbled wp-embed on the former for now)

Comment: you give the same website, also first of all you need create empty theme to check function for example with one line `var_dump(get_template_directory_uri());` to check in both site, maybe some of plugins change display url.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in footer.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" defer="defer" src="<?php echo esc_url( get_stylesheet_directory_uri() );?>/js/name.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, thanks everyone, never mind. turns out it is a server issue -- we have a reverse proxy mount and the asset paths are configured for only one of the blogs.

spent like 4 hours on this! :( -- thanks again for all the help everyone!